# Show UIView above keyboard not working properly

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, nslayoutconstraint, nsnotificationcenter

I'm trying to move the `constraintToBottom.constant` of a `UIView` where my `UITextField` is located above the keyboard once it's shown. I set the `Notification` observer, but for some reason it's not working.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(_:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide(_:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}

@objc func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: Notification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
            self.constraintToBottom.constant = keyboardSize.height
            print("constant", self.constraintToBottom.constant)
        })
    }
}
```

When I print the `constraintToBottom.constant` it shows:

> constant 346.0

And yet, the `UIView` is still not visible above the keyboard as usual. What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

As suggested, the minus does the trick BUT there's also extra space and it looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to re-layout the view

```
self.constraintToBottom.constant = -1 * keyboardSize.height
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
     self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
     print("constant", self.constraintToBottom.constant)
})
```

Comment: I tested this, no change. The keyboard still hovers the view

Comment: Now it does work but it also has some extra space which is not supposed to be there. The bottom constraint is initially set to 0 (based on the Safe Area). See the image in the update above, please

Comment: can you try it without safe area ??

Comment: I set it to the `Superview` instead, but for some reason, I get the same result. I tried 2 different simulators, they both show the same. If I add +50 to the keyboard, depends on the simulator it reduces that gap. But this is not the way to do it. Not sure why there's a gap there.

Comment: Figured it out. It's the tabbar that was messing with it.